# Nodejs - Stylus no create css file from 'styl' file

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

I am using node. In the app i created a folder called 'styles' in the folder i created a file called 'style.styl' now I require to compile this file, I suppose to  have a new 'style.css' file in the same folder. for that i use this function, But not working any help please?

```
var http = require('http'),
express  = require('express'),
path     = require('path'),
jade = require('jade'),
stylus = require('stylus'),//i am requiring stylus
nib = require('nib'), // nib as well
fs = require('fs'),
app      = express();

function compile(str, path) { //dynamically i am comiling here
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .use(nib());
}

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);



app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.use(stylus.middleware({ // i am using midware to take care of styl files. but no result
  src: __dirname + '/styles',
  dest: __dirname + '/styles',
  compile: compile,
  debug: true,
  force: true
}));
```

Any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line `app.use(app.router)`. I suspect your stylus middleware isn't being executed at all because express hits the router and sends a 404 error before stylus because order of middleware matters.

Answer (score 0):

My own I came to know that,  stylus is not working just directly putting the styl file on the root. Instead it requires a folder to notify. I made a static folder to fix this issue.

It works. thanks to all.